# Rerun the program after it ends automatically in octave

Tags: octave

Using OCTAVE only...

How can I rerun the code automatically after it ends. Like I want to make a program in which if the input is incorrect value it will end the program and rerun again.

I tried that by writting there a file name and it works but this will only work until I change my file name.

Comment: On what operating system? Provide some [mre] and much more details in your next question! If on Linux, consider writing some [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script (if so allowed)

Comment: Your shell script (in GNU bash) would repeat the `octave` command...

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: What I asked was. I have one program written in octave. At the end I want to put one question and depending on the answer yes or no I want to re run the code automatically. If answer is yes the code will start running from the first line again.

Comment: Did you read documentation of the [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) ? Are you allowed to code a small C program (maybe with [GTK](http://gtk.org/)....) which would restart `octave` ? For your next question, provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: The real question here is, why do you want to **end** the program and rerun it? Why not just loop until a correct input value is given?

Comment: Actually I am creating a carrom board simulation. At the end I want to ask player to play it again ? If the input will yes program will start again. That's the case.

Comment: Then there's no need to "end" the program. Simply loop until the player doesn't wish to play again, *then* end. By the way, since there are multiple people commenting, if you don't tag someone like @beaker, they won't be notified that you've responded to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your main script in a wrapper script which performs the loop.

```
% In main.m
disp( 'Hello from main' );
Question = "Do you want to rerun? ";
Response = input( Question, 's');
```

```
% in wrapper.m
Response = 'yes';
while strcmp( Response, 'yes' )
  main
end
```